# I am getting that a function is not a function?

Tags: node.js, express

I am querying the database for some information and I am using `await-to-js`. But for some reason it is saying:

```
(node:28524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: to is not a function
```

This is the website for reference:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-to-js

```
const {
  User,
  Connection,
  SystemInfo,
  LocationInfo
} = require('../../db/models');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const to = require('await-to-js');

// Return complete user connections information
router.get('/:id_user', async (req, res) => {
  const { id_user } = req.params;

  let [error, users] = await to(
    User.findOne({
      where: { id_user },
      include: [
        {
          attributes: ['id_connection', 'date'],
          model: Connection,
          include: [
            {
              attributes: ['browser'],
              model: SystemInfo
            },
            {
              attributes: ['country', 'city', 'ip'],
              model: LocationInfo
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
  );

  if (error) {
    // TODO: Log error
    return res.status(502).json({ errorMessage: 'Some error', error });
  }
  console.log(user);
  res.status(200).json(user);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs you linked to, under [**Usage**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-to-js#usage):

```js
import to from 'await-to-js';
// If you use CommonJS (i.e NodeJS environment), it should be:
// const to = require('await-to-js').default;
```

In non-code form (comment mine):

> If you use CommonJS (i.e NodeJS environment), it should be:
>
> ```js
> const to = require('await-to-js').default;
>                               // ^------^ note
> ```